# Inject <customTag> within text using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, text, domdocument

I would like to add a custom tag  within a certain part of a text node using DOMDocument, my problem is that I can't figure out how can I locate that specific part, for example:

> "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.*"

My purpose is to add the tag somewhere this way:

> "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <emphasis>consectetur adipiscing</emphasis>  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.*"

The problem is that every text node is an instance of DOMNode, so I can't properly get the text content of the node and "inject" the tag right in.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far and also when you say *how can I locate that specific part* do you mean select a node and then add the custom tag around a specific word or are there other criteria?

Comment: Yes, I have a DOMNode object with "some content" string, I want to take a part of that text (or just a single word) and inject the tag. So far i'm just testing with phpTester trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Some logic and regex and you are done. Explained in comments.

```php
<?php
// example code
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
$post = from("consectetur", "ut", $string, "<a>");

function from($from,$to, $string, $tag) {
    $frompost = strpos($string, $from); // get the pos of first string
    $topost = strpos($string, $to); // get the post of second string
    $substrfirst = substr($string, 0 , $frompost) . $tag; // trim string for the first word and add concatinate the tag
    $substrsecond = $substrfirst . substr($string, $frompost , strlen($from)); // trim another string starting from the first word and ending the length of the word and combine it with previous result
    $strinbetweenregex = '/(?<='.$from.')(.*)(?='.$to.')/'; // regex to get string in between
    preg_match($strinbetweenregex, $string, $matches); // get regex result
    $restString = substr($string, $topost + strlen($to) , strlen($string)); // get the rest of the string by starting from last str postition + the length of the last str to the length of the str 
    return $substrsecond.  $matches[0] . $to .$tag  . $restString; // return all the string.
}
```

This will give `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</a> labore et dolore magna aliqua.`

This also gives us an inequality. Which is

```php
$frompost < $topost
```

That also means that your first argument should come first from left to right, followed by second argument.

Comment: After a couple of modifications this solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long winded way round the solution, but it basically starts with a DOMNode(or DOMElement) and ends up putting the content back as the same with the changes.  It also attempts to ensure that any content is preserved around it (including markup and other structure).

The idea being to save the HTML of the node to be updated and then just use `str_replace()` to change the content.  This then is imported back into the document (using SimpleXML as I think it's easier, then importing the new node to the DOMDOcument and then replacing the original node with the new one...

```
$source = '<div class="ToReplace">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>';

$textToTag="consectetur adipiscing";
$tag = "emphasis";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($source);

foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName("div") as $div )    {
    $nodeHTML = $doc->saveHTML($div);
    $newHTML = str_replace($textToTag, "<$tag>$textToTag</$tag>", $nodeHTML);
    $newNode = simplexml_load_string($newHTML);
    $import = $doc->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($newNode), true);
    $div->parentNode->replaceChild($import, $div);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```